# How to view the memory map of a running process?

Tags: kernel, ram, process

I want to view the stack location of a running process. How can I view the memory map and find out the memory location of the stack using terminal without using any debuggers.

*Context*:
I am studying bufferoverflow attacks and prevention mechanisms that are used in operating systems. I need to learn how Ubuntu employs ASLR.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`pmap`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/pmap.1.html) will show memory map of a process and all associated processes running if you have the process ID. Perhaps that is what you want?

Comment: I looked at before..But it does not show the expected information

Comment: @Saradiyel, what do you mean?  It shows the information you said you expected; namely the memory map including stack location.

Comment: @psusi, It was my mistake. I didn't run that command as root. So I couldn't view the memory map of processes which running as root. :) Now its ok.